# how to call function inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax

I am trying to call function within ajax success block which is not happening.

Below I have given code which i was tried.

```js
$("#form-data").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var me = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('storeData.store')}}",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      me.callFunc(); // here i need to call that fucntion once data is stored in database
    }
  });
})

$(document).ready(function(e) { // here i need to call that fucntion when page loads
  this.callFunc();
})

function callFunc() { // this is the function needs to call 
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{route('getData.get')}}",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("output data", data)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: me/this is not what you think it is. Just call `callFunc()` without me/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your "callFunc()" without me / this as per below.

```
$("#form-data").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('storeData.store')}}",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      callFunc(); // here i need to call that fucntion once data is stored in database
    }
  });
})

$(document).ready(function(e) { // here i need to call that fucntion when page loads
  callFunc();
})

function callFunc() { // this is the function needs to call 
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{route('getData.get')}}",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("output data", data)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `this`

```js
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        function callFunc() { // this is the function needs to call 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{route('getData.get')}}",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("output data", data)
                }
            })
        }

        $("#form-data").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{route('storeData.store')}}",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    callFunc(); // here i need to call that fucntion once data is stored in database
                }
            });
        });

        callFunc(); // here i need to call that fucntion when page loads
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is globally available so just call it like any other javascript function inside any other function

```
callFunc()
```